# I keep getting this Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I've been banging my head against a wall with this simple comunication between javascript and php.

I have an HTML form which asks the user to input two numbers. It should send those two numbers as JSON to the server (process.php). In the server, it should add the two numbers and send the result back to the JavaScript. After that, it would print the result on the HTML file.

**javascript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calcular').click (function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var numerosJSON = JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/process.php',
            type:'post',
            data: numerosJSON,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(soma){
                                //shows result in a div in the html file
                $('#out').text(soma);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**process.php**

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$numeros = json_decode($json, true);

$fst = $_POST['first'];
$snd = $_POST['second'];

$soma = $fst + $snd;

header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($soma);
```

It does send the request, but I always get an error :

> Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Can you guys lend me a hand on this? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted PHP code you decode the received JSON object but don't use it, rather you try to retrieve the values from `$_POST`. After you decode the object, you will have one array element containing `name` and `value` children per serialized input. If you want to access these elements by name, you'll need to loop over the received and decoded array via [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or while/for. For simplicity I used access by array index in my sample.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$numeros = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$fst = $numeros[0]["value"];
$snd = $numeros[1]["value"];
$soma = $fst + $snd;

header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($soma);
```